# How to recover my terminal vim window when I use ctrl-s to save in vim by mistake?

Tags: command-line, vim, vi

I have been using Visual Studio code a lot lately and like a lot of IDEs you can get used to using CTRL-S to save as it is quicker than using "esc :w" - if you are using vim bindings like I do.

However when I now use a plain terminal window outside of VScode and I use vim I forget that I am not in VS code, I use ctrl-s and unfortunately it seems to freeze the terminal window and I have not found a way to recover it.  Currently I have to kill the terminal window and then recover the file.

How to recover from the `ctrl-s` freeze ?

Comment: `Ctrl-S` can be undone with `Ctrl Q` (The ASCII `XOFF` and `XON` characters used for stopping & starting paper tape readers on Model 35ASR TeleTypes)

Comment: Thanks.  Ahh, that light grey console was loved so much.

Comment: Please post as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Ctrl-S` can be undone with `Ctrl Q` (The ASCII `XOFF` and `XON` characters used for stopping & starting paper tape readers on Model 35ASR TeleTypes).